# store does'nt persist pinia vuejs

Tags: vue.js, state, persist, pinia

i work on vuejs version 2.9 and i want to persist my store when the page is refreshed.

i use pinia and make like the online documentation : https://prazdevs.github.io/pinia-plugin-persistedstate/guide/

main.ts :

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import piniaPluginPersistedstate from 'pinia-plugin-persistedstate';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(createPinia());
const pinia = createPinia()
pinia.use(piniaPluginPersistedstate);

app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

my store :

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const TokenStore = defineStore({
  id: "token",
  state: () => ({
    email:"",
    pseudo: "",
    myid: "",
    nom:"",
    prenom:"",
    role: "",
    token:"",
    avatar:"",
  }),

  persist: true,  

});
```

An idea for the reason of it doesn't work ? Or an other way to persist my store ?

Comment: No idea. It's unknown if there are errors on your side, or whether there is data in LS. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is at the entry point of the application in these lines:

```
app.use(createPinia()); // this is using one instance of pinia
const pinia = createPinia() // here you are creating a second instance of pinia
pinia.use(piniaPluginPersistedstate) // here you are applying a package to the second instance that is not the one which is connected to the vue app.
```

Could you try this instead

```
app.use(pinia) // after the pinia.use declaration
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the import statements and usage of PPS

And use a good sequence in import Statements:

```
import { createApp} from "vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import piniaPluginPersistedstate from 'pinia-plugin-persistedstate'

const app = createApp(App);
const pinia = createPinia();

pinia.use(piniaPluginPersistedstate)
app.use(pinia);

app.mount("#app");
```

Do not forget to name your store.
The name of the store is used to give a key to the storage.
For example:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

    export const useStore = defineStore('nameOfStore', {
      state: () => {
        return {
          someState: 'hello pinia',
        }
      },
      persist: true,
    })
```

The localStorage (if you use the default storage system) will have a key of 'NameOfStore' and values of '{someState: 'hello pinia'}

### Vueuse

if you do not want to use Pinia, you can use a utility from https://vueuse.org/.

npm i @vueuse/core

```
*main.js*
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
createApp(App).use(createPinia()).mount('#app')
*store.js*
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core'
state: () => {
        return {
          someState: useStorage(someState: 'hello pinia'),
        }
```

usage:https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/#usage